# Classic ASP: How to list activated sessions?

Tags: asp-classic

Is there someway to get a list of activated sessions in classic ASP?

I want to limit the number of simultaneus activated sessions.

Comment: Do you have control of the server? I ask only because you may find it easier to go that route if you have the option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a good article which shows a way to do that: [Active User Count Without Global.asa by Josh Painter](http://www.aspfree.com/c/a/asp-code/active-user-count-without-global-asa-by-josh-painter/)

I guess you have to change some details, but this is the way you could approach the problem. The author doesn't use global.asa.

A simpler way would be to hook the `Sesssion_OnStart` and `Session_OnEnd` events in global.asa and adding/removing the item from the list of sessions implemented as an Application variable.

If you just want the **count** of sessions, you could simply doing it this way:

```
Sub Session_OnStart
   Application.Lock
   Application("count") = Application("count") + 1
   Application.Unlock
End Sub

Sub Session_OnEnd
   Application.Lock
   Application("count") = Application("count") - 1
   If Application("count") < 0 then  ' Could only happen if some other function interfers
      Application("count")=0 
   End If
   Application.Unlock
End Sub
```

In your ASP file

```
<%
Response.Write "There are currently " & Application("count") & "active sessions>"
%>
```

Comment: 404 page not found. Perhaps add the info or find it in archive.org?

Answer (score 1):

You can't access one session from another, so there's no built-in way to get a list of all the active sessions. However, you can use `Session_OnStart` and `Session_OnEnd` in global.asa to track the sessions by saving the relevant session info to the `Application` object, a log file, a database etc (depending on exactly what you want to do with the information).

We tend to track the number of active sessions in an `Application` object to get a rough idea of how many people are using a site at any given time (bearing in mind, of course, that people will typically have left the site long before their sessions time out). It's not 100% accurate but it's close enough for a guide to current activity.

If you just want the number of sessions, you can also use Perfmon to track the `Sessions Current` counter (and other related counters) for the `Active Server Pages` performance object. Obviously this assumes access to the server and probably isn't what you want in this case.

For more info on some options, try this article: [How do I count the number of current users / sessions?](http://web.archive.org/web/20091219095226/http://classicasp.aspfaq.com/general/how-do-i-count-the-number-of-current-users/sessions.html) (archived version)

Comment: @MichielvanderBlonk thanks; I replaced the link with the right one.